# How to automatically hide columns in other sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write a VBA function such that when a column in a "Master" sheet is hidden, the same column (of the same name) in all other sheets is also hidden. Below is what I have in my "Master" sheet code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Dim i As Integer, ws As Worksheet

    If IsEntireColumn(Target) = True Then    
        If Target.Hidden = True Then

            For i = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
                For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
                    If ws.Name = "Master" Or ws.Name = "Affiliate Codes" Then
                    Else
                        ws.Cells(1, ColumnIndexReturn(ws.Name, Target.Cells(1, i), 3)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    End If
                Next ws
            Next i 

        End If    
    End If    

End Sub
```

For context, IsEntireColumn is a boolean function that returns `True` if the selected range is indeed entire columns, while ColumnIndexReturn is another function that returns the column index of a column by its name.

Since this is a Worksheet_Change sub, I would expect that each time I hide a column, the corresponding columns in other sheets will also be hidden automatically. However, so far this has not been happening, the columns in the other worksheets are not hiding themselves automatically.

May I know what may be the issue here? Feel free to let me know if any further information is required. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: The `Worksheet_Change` event doesn't trigger when you hide (or show) columns or rows ... I'm not aware of an event that would let you capture this happening

Comment: *let me know if any further information is required* When you single step through the code, which line in your `Sub` doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: You could go with Worksheet_SelectionChanged event and store the range in a global variable (or in a hidden sheet if you're ok with that). If the selectionchanged goes away from a selected column (check the global variable), then check if it's hidden and work from there. Edit: Welp, didn't check if something updated, apparently this is what FunThomas did :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your request is a little bit tricky.

The main reason your code is not doing anything: The `Change`-event is only triggered if content of cells are changed. Showing/hiding a cell (or any other formatting) will not trigger the change-event.

A better event would the the `Selection_Change`-event that is triggered, whenever a cell is selected. However, this is also not working: This event is triggered when you select a column, it is triggered another time when you right click (to select the "Hide"-command), but it is *not* triggered after the column was hidden.

Best idea I came up is to "remember" a selected column in the `Selection_Change` event. When the `Selection_Change` is called the *next* time, do the show/hide logic for the previous remembered columns - sooner or later the user will select another cell. With one exception: When a user selects a different sheet immediately after hiding a column. To address this, we can use the `Worksheet_Deactivate`-event.

I came up with the following piece of code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim lastSelectedColumn As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not lastSelectedColumn Is Nothing Then
        ShowHideColumns lastSelectedColumn
    End If
    
    If IsEntireColumn(Target) Then
        Set lastSelectedColumn = Target
    Else
        Set lastSelectedColumn = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    If Not lastSelectedColumn Is Nothing Then
        ShowHideColumns lastSelectedColumn
        Set lastSelectedColumn = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Sub ShowHideColumns(Target As Range)
    Dim col As Long, ws As Worksheet
    For col = 1 To Target.Columns.Count
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Master" And ws.Name <> "Affiliate Codes" And ws.Name <> Target.Parent.Name Then
                Dim cell As Range
                Set cell = Target.Cells(1, col)
                ws.Cells(1, cell.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = cell.EntireColumn.Hidden
            End If
        Next ws
    Next col
End Sub

Function IsEntireColumn(Target As Range) As Boolean
    IsEntireColumn = (Target.Rows.Count = Target.Parent.Rows.Count)
End Function
```

Note that the code not only *hides* the column(s), but it will also *show* them again.

Comment: The `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange` event might be a further approach for intratabular movements, but possibly slowing down speed; *don't know if available in prior versions*. @FunThomas

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks so much for this. I'm in the process of implementing and experimenting your code.
Just curious though, while hiding a column doesn't get picked up by the worksheet_change, does deleting or colouring it get picked up?

Comment: Coloring: No. Deleting: Yes. But you can find that out easily: Just put the statement `    Debug.Print "Change: " & Target.Address` in the `Worksheet_Change`-Trigger (and open the immediate window: CTRL+G)

Answer (score 3):

@FunThomas, you were 24 minutes quicker

Place this code in module "ThisWorkbook"

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim i As Integer, c As Integer, ws As Worksheet
    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Master").UsedRange.Columns.Count
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            If ws.Name <> "Master" And ws.Name <> "Affiliate Codes" Then
               c = ColumnIndexReturn(ws.Name, Worksheets("Master").Cells(1, i))
               If c <> 0 Then
                  ws.Cells(1, c).EntireColumn.Hidden = Worksheets("Master").Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden
               End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
Private Function ColumnIndexReturn(sSheetName As String, sColumnName As String) As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Worksheets(sSheetName).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If Worksheets(sSheetName).Cells(1, i).Value = sColumnName Then
           ColumnIndexReturn = i
           Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

This code only runs when the user changes the sheet, not on every cell change, also it shows a column again when it is changed to visible in in Master

Comment: On second thought, why would we want to synchronise all sheets at once?
We only need to do that for the parameter of the SheetActivate event, the “Sh” object. Just before you enter the worksheet, synchronising columns for that particular sheet will be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more versatile version of hennep code.

```
Sub SyncMasterColumnVisibility(Optional TargetWorksheet As Worksheet)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Const MasterSheetName As String = "Master"
    Dim Excludes As Variant
    Excludes = Array("Master", "Affiliate Codes")
    
    Dim TargetWorksheets As New Collection
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    If Not TargetWorksheet Is Nothing Then
        TargetWorksheets.Add TargetWorksheet
    Else
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            On Error Resume Next ' In case Match function does not find a match
            If IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Name, Excludes, 0)) Then
                TargetWorksheets.Add ws
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
        Next ws
    End If
    
    Dim MasterSheetColumnVisibility As New Collection
    Dim Cell As Range
    
    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(MasterSheetName).UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            MasterSheetColumnVisibility.Add Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden, CStr(Cell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next
    
    Dim Hidden As Boolean
    Dim tWs As Variant ' Use variant type because the collection may contain different object types
    For Each tWs In TargetWorksheets
        For Each Cell In tWs.UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
            On Error Resume Next ' In case Match function does not find a match
            Hidden = MasterSheetColumnVisibility(CStr(Cell.Value))
            If Err.Number = 0 Then Cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = Hidden
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
        Next
    Next tWs
End Sub
```

Using the `Workbook_SheetActivate` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    SyncMasterColumnVisibility Sh
End Sub
```

Using the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate` event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Const MasterSheetName As String = "Master"
    If Sh.Name = MasterSheetName Then SyncMasterColumnVisibility
End Sub
```